# debian squeeze bind wizard application

Tags: debian, bind

I need a program to automatically generate bind zone files and rev files. any recommended program for this. but i dont need web based application. i need cli tools.

changing bind zone files is so complex for newbie bind users. a simple wizard base program.

**simple**, **security configurations** and **debian compatibly settings** (path and etc) can be good feature of that.

Comment: Why wouldn't a web application work?

Comment: @ShaneMadden i want to handle web server by my own ... i dont need web server just for this usage. of i want to install lighthttpd ... why i must install apache or nginx beside them?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to having a tool generate these files for you (I am not aware of such a tool existing), you may want to look into the tools **named-checkzone** and **named-checkconf** from the bind9utils package.

Those allow you to check whether the zone files and configuration files are syntactically correct.

Do you want the tools to generate zone files for yourself or for people so they can update their own zone files? If the former it's really a much better idea to learn it yourself, because it is not that hard and once you have a working zone file updating it is almost trivial. Then use the above utilities to check the syntax.

In case of the latter I would say they write you with a request to update and you do it by hand. You can always hide that email request in a fancy web based tool that makes it seem it is automated. ;-)

Comment: i used theme for check db files . but i need cli base for generate standard zone files. for newbies in bind. not stupid web based project for use that.

Comment: See my updated answer. That's the best I can come up with right now.